# Arduino-based oscilloscope: attenuate the input by varying reference voltage?

Tags: adc, oscilloscope

I don't have a proper oscilloscope. I don't have the budget to buy one, even a used one. I have to roll my own. :(

The plan is to use an Arduino Leonardo or Due as a combined A/D and USB interface and write an app on my Mac to display the waveform. Now the problem is how should I give it V/div options without losing resolution?

I am wondering whether this will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flDGEv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By changing the AREF voltage I can change the full range voltage of the DAC. Will this produce the effect of giving me lower V/div without losing resulotion?

For higher V/div, would a simple single digital pot work?

Comment: Take a close look at the [AREF specification for the chip](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf) you're using (page 365). There are limits on the allowable values. For higher V/div, you'd have to find a digital pot that could handle the voltage being measured. Most are limited to voltages within their own supply rails.

Comment: The best prices for a DSO nano costs within 10% of a genuine Arduino Due.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I have a Arduino Due clone. Those are cheap if ordered from Shenzhen. DSO Nano is, however, not quite cheap even from Shenzhen.

Comment: Yet, I doubt it's worthwhile when you can get a ready-made device with equal or better performance for less than US$50.

Comment: However, instead of adjusting V(AREF) you would probably be better off using an op-amp with a resistor network to select the prescaling of the input signal. This would also allow you to switch between prescaling factors above and below 1, and is probably a lot cheaper than a digital potentiometer.

Comment: @HannoBinder My Arduino Due clone cost me US$10, and I have a monthly budget cap of $120 including meals. If I buy a $50 scope I need to save up for quite a while.

Comment: @HannoBinder The V/div is controlled by the host computer so a d-pot is called for no matter what.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Sounds like a real tight budget. But are you aware that you'll probably spend dozens of (unpaid!) hours building and programming your 'scope? And that you'll also easily have to spend more than an additional US$10 for the other parts besides the Arduino?

Comment: I was actually thinking of a digitally controlled op-amp circuit. By "switching" individual resistors on or off, the µC can define the amplification of the input stage through GPIO pins as desired.

Comment: If you want an even cheaper scope, the audio input of a PC works about as well. You don't need to write any software, and there's probably already an adjustable microphone gain.

Comment: @HannoBinder I am a student and it is virtually impossible for non-graduates to find a job here (China) so I have time to kill. Also parts here, if ordered from Shenzhen, can get ridiculously cheap from time to time (US$1 = 100 `2N7000`s, hello,) especially for jellybean parts.

Comment: @PhilFrost Well that is just not good enough for me, and I don't want to fry my out-of-warranty MacBook. Frying an Arduino is one thing, frying my MacBook is another.

Comment: @HannoBinder I also have another reason why I want to build a Leonardo-based USB scope: I have a busted Leonardo clone and I scrapped its MCU chip. If my experiment worked I can roll one with a form factor of a flash drive, using essentially scrap parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking of this kind of op-amp input stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzKaa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SW1-3 here represent three GPIO pins of the µC which are then used to set the feedback voltage divisor.

To answer your question:

> By changing the AREF voltage I can change the full range voltage of
>   the DAC. Will this produce the effect of giving me lower V/div without
>   losing resulotion?

Yes, this will actually work as desired. But you'll have to be careful because the ADC may be destroyed if it sees an input voltage that's higher than V(AREF), even if it's still far below Vcc.

> For higher V/div, would a simple single digital pot work?

Not sure about that. Depending on the signal's source impedance the additional load of the voltage divider may degrade/distort the signal. Also, check the potentiometer's transfer characteristics for different frequencies; and have you thought about AC signals which may go below GND?

Comment: Actually I got a few d-pot chips as a parts swap with my friend. He got several extra d-pots and I swapped my MCUs (I stock `ATtiny85` and `ATmega328P` for their being cheap from Shenzhen and Arduino compatibility.) with those.

Comment: About that AC going below GND issue, can it be fixed using the differential ADC feature of the MCU, and raise both inputs to 1/2Vcc?

Comment: I used a d-pot instead of the switched resistors but anyhow it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution will be Vref/1024 if it is a 10 bit ADC. 
If Vref = 5V, resolution is about 4.88mV. 
If Vref = 2.5V resolution is 2.44mV. 
The bigger the scale the lower the resolution.
On the other hand, you can buy an old oscilloscope for $25.

Comment: Well here in a fantastic country called China even an old scope would cost me more than US$100. With my $120/month budget cap I have to work around it. Here I meant digital resolution not analog.